# How does the tag "status-declined" explanation in the faq make any sense?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

It says in the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#declined-closed):

> #### Why was my feature/bug declined or closed without explanation?
>
> Meta Stack Overflow has been around for a while, and as a result, many issues have been considered in the past. If your feature request has been marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) without a comment, it is likely because there is another question that approaches the same topic and a conclusion has been reached. Perhaps you could try searching for your idea with different search terms, hopefully that will find the original discussion.

This should never happen. If a feature request is closed for either of these reasons, there should be an explanation.

Now, if it is closed because it was discussed before, *it should be closed **as duplicate***, and tagged `status-*` *additionally*.

I think the current version doesn't convey any useful information and is at best misleading. So it should be changed not only in wording but also in meaning or removed altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only thought here is that the FAQ is there for a reason:

**To prevent the mods here from having to provide explanations for every single request (and every possible variation) that comes in.** Instead of repeating themselves, they add the tag and move on.

The FAQ is meant to explain some of the more popular actions taken here, so you don't have to ask why. The obligation is on you to locate the prior discussion. I'm sure they have enough to do.

Comment: Yes, obviously. My point was, that such a question should be "closed as duplicate", which will include a message **that it was closed as duplicate** (in other words, a reason). You don't have to first go to the faq to figure out why your feature-request was declined, it says so *right there under your question*.

Comment: @bitmask You wrote `If a feature request is closed for either of these reasons, there should be an explanation.` Again, **the FAQ is explaining the reason so the mods don't have to**. That is the point of a FAQ. However, I am only guessing. I really have no insight. Only the mods can explain why feature requests are treated this way, while duplicate questions are closed w/explanation.

Comment: The relevant part is this: `If your feature request has been marked as status-bydesign or status-declined without a comment, it is likely because there is another question that approaches the same topic and a conclusion has been reached.` So, the **only explanation** I would get by this faq is that my question was a duplicate. This is not something I should have to dig out of the faq. It should be immediately communicated by closing a question as a duplicate. In any case, the faq contains irrelevant information. This should not be the case for an faq.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, if it is closed because it was discussed before, it should be closed as duplicate, and tagged status-* additionally

It might not be an actual duplicate.

For instance, there are an *endless* variety of suggestions for adding things like private messaging or non-anonymous voting. A lot of them are duplicates, or close enough that they get closed as such. But some are pretty novel. They'll still get declined (no matter how "clever" you get in the implementation, opening up folks to harassment is a bad idea) but they won't necessarily get closed.

If the person declining doesn't comment, there's a pretty good chance that's because the reason is already in someone else's comment, someone else's answer, or one of the questions showing up in the right-hand sidebar.

Comment: I find closing as duplicate gets overused here on meta to link askers to answers on another question anyway. So +1 for not advocating closure on similar requests.

Comment: Yeah... I'm a big fan of closing questions that propose superficially-different implementations of problematic features without addressing previous complaints, but not every request or bug report fits previous discussions.

Comment: So, it's similar enough to warrant no comment, because it's reason is easy to find via search, but it's not a duplicate? Dropping a link or a brief comment still feels more constructive than just retagging and going away.

Comment: @bitmask: my point is that there's nearly *always* an explanation for the decline to be found; AFAIK, that verbiage is to forestall complaints from folks who've seen stuff declined with no explicit, "official" answer. Comments to the effect of, "see the massively up-voted answer by a community member on your massively down-voted question" are really just noise in most cases.